# Outlook add in: remove a calendar event

Tags: events, outlook-web-addins

I have an Outlook add in to create a calendar event from my task pane.

Once created, I would like to delete the event in some cases. Must I use the graph api to do that?
If so, I have seen in the API:

```
DELETE /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/events/{id}
```

I have the 'event id', but I need the **user id** (or userPrincipalName). What I can get from Office.context.mailbox.userProfile is 'displayName' & 'emailAddress'

Besides, I need a **Bearer header**, but how can I get that token with my add in info?

Maybe I can delete the event differently...

Thanks in advance,
Diego

Comment: Are you trying to delete event from your own calendar (account owned by you)?

Comment: Yes, I need to delete an event I have just created in my calendar, for example

Comment: We don't have addin (OfficeJS) API to delete the calendar event. You can achieve this using REST API. Please check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/use-rest-api) on how to use REST APIs from Outlook Addin. You will need to use getCallbackTokenAsync() addin API to get the REST Token.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't have addin (OfficeJS) API to delete the calendar event. You can achieve this using REST API. Please check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/use-rest-api) on how to use REST APIs from Outlook Addin. You will need to use getCallbackTokenAsync() addin API to get the REST Token.